# java.lang.SecurityException: no manifiest section for signature file (RSA, SF, DSA files and MANIFEST.MF excluded)

Tags: java, ant, jar

Below is my ant build jar target:

```
<target name="build jar" depends="compile">

        <mkdir dir="${dist.home}" />

        <jar destfile="${dist.home}/${app.name}.jar" basedir="${build.home}/classes">
            <zipgroupfileset dir="${lib.home}" includes="*.jar" excludes="*.RSA, *.SF, *.DSA, META-INF/MANIFEST.MF" />  

            <manifest>
                <attribute name = "Main-Class" value = "com.karthik.publisher"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>

    </target>
```

When I run/execute the jar from command prompt, I get the below error

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: no manifiest section for signature file entry javax/mail/SecuritySupport.class
        at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.verifySection(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(Unknown Source)
```

As you can see I excluded RSA, SF and DSA files and MANIFEST.MF from each jar but I am still getting this exception.

Comment: Unzip the generated JAR file and checks what files are available in it's META-INF dir.

Comment: After I extracted the JAR file, I see .RSA, .SF, MANIFEST.MF, mimetype.default, mailcap.default files in META-INF dir. It seems like these files are not excluded in build/jar. I suspect something wrong in build jar target.

Answer (score 0):

The `excludes` definition in your `build jar` task only covers .RSA .SF and .DSA files in the root of your jar file. However they are located in the `META-INF` subdirectory.

- `*.RSA`-> covers RSA files in the root of the zip/jar file to be merged
- `**/*.RSA`-> covers RSA files everywhere in the zip/jar file to be merged
- `META-INF/*.*` -> covers all files in the META-INF directory

I would recommend to you to use the third alternative, as I don't see a reason for any jar to place a file in the META-INF directory of the merged jar.

Comment: I tried the third option but still I see all the files existing in META-INF folder

Comment: Have you removed the spaces in the `excludes` string?

Comment: I have removed the spaces. I think the issue is with excludes in zipgroupfileset. I have changed it to <fileset dir="${lib.home}" casesensitive="no">
           <exclude name="**/*.RSA" />
           <exclude name="**/*.SF" />
           <exclude name="**/*.DSA" />
           <exclude name="META-INF/*.*" />
          </fileset>. Now I am not getting security exception but Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/JMSException